# Checking whether my pgAdmin III is a 32 or 64 bits version

Tags: windows, pgadmin-3

I need to check if my pgAdmin III is a 32 or 64 bits version. Where can I find this information? The About... menu in pgAdmin GUI does not mention it (only the version number like 1.20).

I've looked for this on the net, without success...

**EDIT:**

I get a win32 error when pgAdmin crashes (connection lost). See image below (sorry my Windows is a french version):

[image]

Comment: I think it is whatever your Postgres server is (if you downloaded the 64bit server, you have a 64bit pgAdmin). Also ProcessExplorer displays this information when the exe is running.

Comment: I did download `postgresql-9.4.5-1-windows-x64.exe`. But I get a win32 error (?) when pgAdmin III crashes (see edit in my post).

Comment: So what is the error you get? Win32 is pretty generic. The API in Windows is still named "Win32" even if it is 64bit

Comment: Just updated my post...

Answer (score 2):

From [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/636184/11116)

> The easiest way, without installing another program or running the file, is just to **right click on the file, choose Properties, and then go the the Compatibility tab. If there are no greyed out options and Windows XP and 9x modes are offered, it's 32-bit.** If there are greyed out options and Vista is the earliest mode offered, it's 64-bit. No need to start the application at all.
>
> If the application is already started, you can of course still use the *32 idea mentioned in other answers. However, this is not available in Windows 8.x and its new task manager. Fortunately, you can enable a Platform column by right-clicking on the column headers in the Details tab and choosing Select columns. The column will contain either "32-bit" or "64-bit" as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your image path may give that away:

```
get-wmiobject win32_process | where {$_.Name -like "pgadmin3.exe"} | select -property Name,ExecutablePath | fl
```

Comment: Don't understand your answer...

Comment: What is the ExecutablePath in your output?